# Why does CMake fail in Powershell, but work in MinGW64 MSYS2 prompt?

Tags: c, cmake, msys2

I have a CMake project. Cmake.exe runs correctly within the `MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit` bash prompt when a few packages have been pre-installed using `pacman` (from the MSYS2 prompt.)

The command is:

`CMake .`

If I run the same CMake command from the `Windows Command Prompt` or from a `Powershell` prompt, the execution fails.

In general, what is the contextual difference between the `MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit` prompt and the Command Prompt which might let one command work, and the other fail?

---

*As an aside, in my particular case, the error I get in the Command Prompt is:*

`CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message): Could NOT find Iconv (missing: Iconv_LIBRARY) (found version "1.16")`

Comment: The default generator/compiler is different for both command lines afaik; mingw uses it's own gcc version with import librarys ending in .a; the standard windows command promt uses the visual studio compiler by default which has import libraries using the extension `.lib`. There's a good chance that the installed package versions are not compatible. Btw: the name of the executable is `cmake(.exe)`; I recommend using `cmake` (all lower case); otherwise you may make a habit of something that doesn't work on case sensitive file systems...